# Splitting applicationContext to multiple files

Tags: spring, configuration

What is the correct way to split Spring's configuration to multiple xml files?

At the moment I have

- `/WEB-INF/foo-servlet.xml`
- `/WEB-INF/foo-service.xml`
- `/WEB-INF/foo-persistence.xml`

My `web.xml` has the following:

```
<servlet>
    <description>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</description>
    <servlet-name>intrafest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/foo-*.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/foo-*.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

The actual questions:

- Is this approach *correct/best*?
- Do I really need to specify the config locations both in the `DispatcherServlet` *AND* the `context-param` sections?

What do I need to keep in mind to be able to reference beans defined in `foo-servlet.xml` from `foo-service.xml`? Does this have something to do with specifying `contextConfigLocation` in `web.xml`?

**Update 1:**

I'm using *Spring* framework 3.0. It's my understanding that I don't need to do resource importing like this:

```
 <import resource="foo-services.xml"/>
```

Is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I find the following setup the easiest.

Use the default config file loading mechanism of [DispatcherServlet](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet):

> The framework will, on initialization
>   of a DispatcherServlet, look for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml
>   in the WEB-INF directory of your web
>   application and create the beans
>   defined there (overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with
>   the same name in the global scope).

In your case, simply create a file `intrafest-servlet.xml` in the `WEB-INF` dir and don't need to specify anything specific information in `web.xml`.

In `intrafest-servlet.xml` file you can use [import](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-xml-import) to compose your XML configuration.

```
<beans>
  <bean id="bean1" class="..."/>
  <bean id="bean2" class="..."/>

  <import resource="foo-services.xml"/>
  <import resource="foo-persistence.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Note that the Spring team actually prefers to load multiple config files when creating the (Web)ApplicationContext. If you still want to do it this way, I think you don't need to specify both context parameters (`context-param`) *and* servlet initialization parameters (`init-param`). One of the two will do. You can also use commas to specify multiple config locations.

Comment: +1 - my setup looks just like this. Although I don't think there are really any practical advantages/disadvantages to this setup vs specifying multiple config files in web.xml - it just seems like semantics

Comment: I definitely think that the default config is advantageous: convention over configuration. Instead of specifying multiple config files with *extra config*, you have only one *default* "top-level" config file that will import those same files you would otherwise have to specify anyway.

Comment: When you are using import be carefull not to import the same file multiple times, (import inside import and so on) as it will cause multiple beans to be created and will lead to a hard to find errors.

Comment: Where should I put `foo-persistence.xml` and how should I reference its resource path? When creating a war, persistence units are not found.

Answer (score 29):

Mike Nereson has this to say on his blog at:

http://blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring/

> There are a couple of ways to do this.
>
> **1. web.xml contextConfigLocation**
>
> Your first option is to load them all into your Web application
>   context via the  ContextConfigLocation element. You’re already going
>   to have your primary applicationContext  here, assuming you’re writing
>   a web application. All you need to do is put some white space between
>   the declaration of the next context.
>
> ```
>   <context-param>
>       <param-name> contextConfigLocation </param-name>
>       <param-value>
>           applicationContext1.xml
>           applicationContext2.xml
>       </param-value>
>   </context-param>
>
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class>
>           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       </listener-class>
>   </listener>
> ```
>
> The above uses carriage returns. Alternatively, yo could just put in a
>   space.
>
> ```
>   <context-param>
>       <param-name> contextConfigLocation </param-name>
>       <param-value> applicationContext1.xml applicationContext2.xml </param-value>
>   </context-param>
>
>   <listener>
>       <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
>   </listener>
> ```
>
> **2. applicationContext.xml import resource**
>
> Your other option is to just add your primary applicationContext.xml
>   to the web.xml and then use import statements in that primary context.
>
> In `applicationContext.xml` you might have…
>
> ```
>   <!-- hibernate configuration and mappings -->
>   <import resource="applicationContext-hibernate.xml"/>
>
>   <!-- ldap -->
>   <import resource="applicationContext-ldap.xml"/>
>
>   <!-- aspects -->
>   <import resource="applicationContext-aspects.xml"/>
> ```
>
> **Which strategy should you use?**
>
> **1.** I always prefer to load up via **web.xml**.
>
> Because , this allows me to keep all contexts isolated from each
>   other. With tests, we can load just the contexts that we need to run
>   those tests. This makes development more modular too as components
>   stay `loosely coupled`, so that in the future I can extract a package
>   or vertical layer and move it to its own module.
>
> **2.** If you are loading contexts into a `non-web application`, I would use the `import` resource.

Comment: Copies article http://blog.codehangover.com/load-multiple-contexts-into-spring/ without citation.

Answer (score 16):

There are two types of contexts we are dealing with:

**1**: root context (parent context. Typically include all jdbc(ORM, Hibernate) initialisation and other spring security related configuration)

**2**: individual servlet context (child context.Typically Dispatcher Servlet Context and initialise all beans related to spring-mvc (controllers , URL Mapping etc)).

Here is an example of web.xml which includes multiple application context file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web Application example</display-name>

    <!-- Configurations for the root application context (parent context) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xml <!-- JDBC related context -->
            /WEB-INF/spring/security/spring-security-context.xml <!-- Spring Security related context -->
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configurations for the DispatcherServlet application context (child context) -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Great answer. Distinction between root and child is key.

Answer (score 6):

@eljenso : intrafest-servlet.xml webapplication context xml will be used if the application uses SPRING WEB MVC.

Otherwise the @kosoant configuration is fine.

Simple example if you dont use SPRING WEB MVC, but want to utitlize SPRING IOC :

In web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then, your application-context.xml will contain: `<import resource="foo-services.xml"/>`
these import statements to load various application context files and put into main application-context.xml.

Thanks and hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of [modular-spring-contexts](https://gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts).

This is a small utility library to allow a more modular organization of spring contexts than is achieved by using [Composing XML-based configuration metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-xml-import). `modular-spring-contexts` works by defining modules, which are basically stand alone application contexts and allowing modules to import beans from other modules, which are exported ín their originating module.

The key points then are

- control over dependencies between modules
- control over which beans are exported and where they are used
- reduced possibility of naming collisions of beans

A simple example would look like this:

File `moduleDefinitions.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:module="http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts xsd/modular-spring-contexts.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <module:module id="serverModule">
        <module:config location="/serverModule.xml" />
    </module:module>

    <module:module id="clientModule">
        <module:config location="/clientModule.xml" />
        <module:requires module="serverModule" />
    </module:module>

</beans>
```

File `serverModule.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:module="http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts xsd/modular-spring-contexts.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="serverSingleton" class="java.math.BigDecimal" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="123.45" />
        <meta key="exported" value="true"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

File `clientModule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:module="http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.gitlab.com/SpaceTrucker/modular-spring-contexts xsd/modular-spring-contexts.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <module:import id="importedSingleton" sourceModule="serverModule" sourceBean="serverSingleton" />

</beans>
```

Comment: thanks @SpaceTrucker! seems like you've created exactly what we also need. not sure why rich spring community didn't create something similar before...