# Multiple applicationContext.xml not working in Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

My project hierarchy is as below:

```
com.somepackage.package1
-- applicationContext.xml
-- Beans....
-- Other packages.
com.somepackage.package2
-- applicationContext.xml
-- Beans....
-- Other Packages.
```

I have configured both of them correctly in web.xml, when I remove one file, the other one is picked properly, but when both are placed, spring is not able to resolve which one to pick. How to resolve this issue, any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am doing the same but it's not working in my case.

Comment: Are you able to post your web.xml?