# Multiple Spring Contexts with ContextLoaderListener and DelegatingFilterProxy "No bean named exception"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, intellij-idea

I was having problems loading multiple contexts with ContextLoaderListener via this in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/dao-context.xml
        WEB-INF/service-context.xml
        WEB-INF/security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jsonpCallbackFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter kept giving me a "No bean named 'jsonpCallbackFilter' is defined" which is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123516/getting-exception-no-bean-named-springsecurityfilterchain-is-defined). It wasn't giving me the error if I put all the configuration in the dispatcher-servlet.xml and, for some reason, the solution for the other question was not working for me.

My current solution is importing everything in the dispatcher-servlet [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files):

```
<import resource="dao-context.xml" />
<import resource="service-context.xml" />
```

[from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files).

Does anybody know why this works and the above doesn't? Is it O.K. to import them via the servlet.xml while leaving the web.xml alone? I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: have you tried to change WEB-INF/*-context.xml?

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between the way Spring handles `application-context.xml` and `*-servlet.xml` files.

`application-context.xml` is used for general configuration, such as dataSource, annotationDriven etc

`*-servlet.xml` is used for configuring your servlet e.g. views, template for example jsp.

Note: Beans in `*-servlet.xml` can refer to beans in `application-context.xml` but not the other way around.