# How to load spring beans for multiple jar file in a war based application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a war based spring web application project which internally has multiple jar files. I am using maven setup to build jars and war file. Each jar file has a set of beans that needs to be loaded and i am not able to do so.

In each of the jar file i have defined a beans.xml file . But the beans are not getting loaded automatically. I have tried loading the beans.xml file from:
a) src/main/resources
b) src/main/resources/META-INF
c) src/main/resources/META-INF/spring
It doesnt work.

My Question: How to prepare the application context for such scenarios? War based app with multiple jars.

Comment: How do you start your spring context? Do the spring-files have all the same name? In your service.jar, name your context appContext-service.xml, in your web-app, name in appContext-web.xml, place them all in the same location. In your context-loader, specify the location with classpath:appContext-*.xml. I think this should work, but didn't try it.

Comment: Do you use <import> tags to import other XMLs from the main application context?

Comment: You can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600095/splitting-applicationcontext-to-multiple-files

Answer (score 2):

If your are packaging your application as a webapp one, then you can simply add a file named *yourservletname-servlet.xml* and include all resources from your jar files using the `<import />` element.

Spring, behind the scenes, will scan the file mentioned above [by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) including all beans declared in the files imported.

Here is how your *servletname-servlet.xml* should look like (xml namespace and schemas declaration are ommited for brevity sake):

```xml
<beans>
  <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/beans.xml"/>
</beans>
```

*I suggest the use of the **META-INF** as your context config files location.*

This will scan all bean declaration files named *beans.xml* under *META-INF* folder under the root of your classpath, which assumes that those files **must** be under *src/main/resources/META-INF/* in your project structure when using Maven as your build tool (so they can get copied directely under *jar_root_path/META-INF/*).

Otherwise, if you are not using the default *-servlet.xml* file, you can specify a custom application context descriptor using the `contextConfigLocation` as follows:

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simple 
    import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/beans.xml"/

Where each jar contains beans.xml file under META-INF folder.It will scan each jar and load beans.xml file and creates beans based on these XMLs files.

Answer (score 0):

You mention beans.xml, is this a CDI project or a standard Spring project ?

Using maven, everything under src/main/resources gets packaged at the top level of your JAR. So if you had a file in src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml, then you should load it using "/META-INF/beans.xml" or define it in your spring context as "classpath:/META-INF/beans.xml".