# servlet in context with path throws exception: Request processing failed with java.net.ConnectException

Tags: spring, exception, servlets

most similar questions asked have NullPointerExceptions, but I think my issue is different. I am using Spring with Maven, Webflow, and Apache Tiles 2.

To be honest, I got no clue what's going on. If anyone can help that would be great. Thank you all in advance!

Error message:

> ```
> INFO : project.toplevel.HomeController - Welcome home!
>
> Oct 19, 2016 10:44:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/toplevel]
>         threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
>         org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: I/O Error reading
>         definitions.] with root cause
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>         at... [various]
> ```

in my web.xml:

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <description></description>
>     <display-name>appServlet</display-name>
>     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>
>             /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
>             /WEB-INF/spring/webflow-context.xml
>         </param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

HomeController.java:

> ```
> public class HomeController {
>    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
>    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
>    public String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
>        logger.info("Welcome home!");
>        return "displayHome";
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: "org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: I/O Error reading
        definitions.] with root cause ", since you are loading multiple file in contextConfigLocation,  they may not correctly parsed. Check if you have added them correctly http://stackoverflow.com/a/20759824/410677

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. Great idea, but it is possible doing this. At least it has worked in my previous project and I've seen it in other ones as well... Could still be, but are there other ideas?